# How to make dropdown menu with delay (JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a dropdown menu, you need to do to submenu falls with a delay.

This is an [example][1] of how I implemented at the moment.

As soon as the button the mouse is over using `setTimeout` launching the countdown until the menu appears, if the cursor is removed from button, then cancel the timeout using `clearTimeout`.

Can't understand why it doesn't work.

`Transition` not working with `display: none`, so that's not an option.

how to fix to get it working?

Comment: PLease include your code in the question. Fiddles should be supplementary, not necessary to understand the question.

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs directly into your question. // Your submenus are made visible via CSS, by the rule `.menu ul li:hover > .submenu` - that happens immediately, if you want to introduce a delay using JavaScript, you will first of all have to remove that rule, and then do the whole thing in JS.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is useless since you haven't included `jQuery`. You are aware that your source code requires the **`jQuery library`** right? If not then I suggest you read things before grabbing free source code and trying to paste it into your own stuff.

Comment: I apologize for improper registration issue,  i add code in question

Answer (score 1):

The CSS `transition`s won't work with `display: block;` or `display: none;`. You can use jQuery [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```js
$(function () {
  $("ul").hide();
  $("a").mouseover(function () {
    $("ul").delay(1000).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
a {display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; padding: 5px; color: #000; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 3px; line-height: 1;}
.btn {margin-bottom: -1px;}
ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; border: 1px solid #ccc;}
ul {padding: 5px; background-color: #fff; width: 100px;}
ul li a {display: block; border-width: 0; border-top-width: 1px; border-radius: 0}
ul li:first-child a {border-top: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">Menu</a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```